# Example of a phenomenon from real life where there is a limit going to infinity

Tags: limits

I haven't been able to find examples in real life where we have a function or sequence such that the limit goes to infinity when the independent variable goes to infinity.   The only one so far is related to the *Coastline paradox* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox).  Another one that I thought is the "size" of the universe, but I am not very familiar how to even model that problem.

I'd appreciate any example provided.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "a function in real life"? Things in real life are finite (both the independent variable and the function value). In models that try to describe phenomena in the real world, $\infty$ can sometimes be used as an approximation for a quantity which is large compared to the scale on which it is usually considered - but that doesn't mean that the quantity really becomes infinitely large.

Comment: That said, a lot of functional relationships that occur in real world models have the property that the function value tends to infinity if the independent variable does so. E.g., the position $x$ of a free particle in one dimension with fixed velocity $v$ is, at time $t$, given by $x(t) = x(0) + vt$, so $x(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$ (assuming that $v > 0$). The acceleration $a$ of a mass $m$ by a force $F$ is given by $a = F/m$, so if you can control the force and thus interpret it as independent variable, you have $a \to \infty$ as $F \to \infty$. [...]

Comment: [...] Same for the kinetic energy of a particle if you interpret it is a function of the mass (for fixed velocity). A simple model for the growth of a population $p$ over time $t$ without resource limit yields that $p$ grows exponentially in $t$, so again $p(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$ (consequentially, the model necessarily breaks down at some point - which is not a surprise, though, since in real life there is not growth without resource limit). But somehow I don't think that those example are what you are really asking for - could you be a bit more specific what you are looking for?

Comment: I remember thinking in high school that when a person sits down then they bounce up a little, and come down and bounce up again, etc.  Obviously a simple mathematical model is that the infinite series of times taken has a finite sum.  But mostly I just chuckled at the thought of all the other students in class bouncing.  :-)

Comment: Imagine a stock produces a regular dividend, say, $1 per quarter.  To stock owners that is a stream of income.  Of course, inflation makes the present values of the payments steadily decrease.  A reasonable benchmark for the price of the stock today is to take the infinite sum of the present values of the future payments.

Comment: Are you sure you want both the independent variable and the limit to go to infinity? If so almost any function will work. If one apple costs 1 dollar than infinitely many apples will cost infinitely many dollars.

Answer (score 2):

What about the infinite summing of some fractions?

This one is well-known for **not** becoming infinitely large:

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^4} + ...$$

~Proof:

[image]

This one is well-known for becoming infinitely large:

$$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + ...$$

Answer (score 2):

What counts and what doesn't depends a lot on how one defines "real" and "life" (for me the function $y(z)=z^2+1$ or $1/z$ is definitely more real than Napoleon: I can play with them right here and right now and they play with me in the most surprising and unpredictable ways. Try to do it with Napoleon and you'll see that there are some difficulties, so I don't really understand why the calculus textbook talk so much about "real life" examples most of which seem hopelessly contrived to me when the mathematics itself is a vast reality with many things more interesting from the sightseeing point than pyramids of Egypt and beaches of Canary islands and (IMHO) our actual task, as math educators, is to teach the students to navigate that reality comfortably and appreciate its beauty without any props from or applications to the physical world (like when they teach poetry, they don't expect a poem to explain how to make french fries or to fix a broken bicycle chain).  But OK, let's stick to the boring anthropomorphic experience.

An optimistic example: the amount of the money in a bank account that pays you some interest. You can play with various rules of paying interest here to see how fast/slow it will grow in each case. In reality most banks collapse at some point (some simultaneously with the state) and this collapse can easily happen during the lifespan of a single generation.

Another example: Take a flashlight on a cloudless night and direct it straight up. Some photons will escape the Earth atmosphere, so their distance from Earth will go up without limit as time progresses.

Yet another one: human greed and consumption against the technological progress. It may be not immediately clear how exactly and in what units to measure them, but the more stuff becomes available, the more is consumed and wanted. Diogenes was content with an old barrel, a nearby fountain and occasional donations of food, demonstrating that that is all that is really necessary (at least in the climate of Athens) and now (almost) everybody cannot live without the latest version of i-phone and the trend continues.

Actually, any time something is (believed to be) going up without limit, most dependent variables also tend to infinity: the number of books vs. the number of writers who ever lived, the number of stars that can be seen vs. the power of our telescopes, the number of good (and also bad) ideas vs. the number of thinking people, and so on, and so forth.